# Writing a Search and Match application

Tags: c#

I'm sure this answer has been answer but im such a novice I cant figure it out. I'm trying to make a program that will take a few excel workbooks and matching any last names and then show then ether in a data grid or a new worksheet. I`ve very green to MySQL and SQL and am wondering if I should go that route.

I Know in access you can make a query to do what I want but how would I make my C# application run the query? I'm not looking for pieces of code I am just asking for advice on logic. I know how to connect to the databases also.. I just don't know how to program a look up functions or some sort of find match functions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sheets are tabular then you can use ADO.NET to populate a dataset that can be easily filtered down or even do a select query directly against the sheet.  Search ADO.NET and Excel it should be easy to find.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I`ve looked over the msdn and I cannot find much references for sample code. I`ll keep looking but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.